# adding image from excel to word using mail merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, mail-merge

I'm using mail merge to generate a word document from an excel sheet and some cells contain images (office 2013).
Is it possible to export them as well to word directly with mail merge without putting them in files in the hard disk ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your export question but one thing I do know is the image(s) must be completely within the cell boundaries in order to sort the spreadsheet and have the images move with their associated row/column. If sorting requires this, surely exporting (if possible) would too.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).